# Can I hook into update loop of ARCore without Sceneform or OpenGL?

Tags: android, arcore

I am trying to do something when a new frame is created. I know of `OnUpdateListener` for a scene with sceneform and the possibility of hooking into `onDrawFrame` in Open GL. However, I would like to keep my implementation independent from a renderer. Therefore my idea is to listen for frame update in ARCore itself. I thought about repeatedly calling `update` method in ARCore's Session to get current frame (polling). But this method seems to do more than just returning the current/last frame.
Is it possible to listen for frame update in ARCore?

I would like to do that in order to implement my own mechanism to listen for events when a plane or reference image is detected.